# AdMob GADBannerView delay when presenting new VC

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gadbannerview

I am using AppDelegate to configure a banner view, and its delegates. Then displaying the banner on two VC's: ViewController, and SecondViewController. The banners show up properly, but with two visual mishaps.

1. On app open, there's about a 2-3 second delay for the test banner to load up. When I was using IB, the banners showed up instantly.
2. When transitioning from ViewController -> SecondViewController via segue (Present Modally / Over Full Screen / Cross Disolve / No Animation), there's a delay of about 1-2 seconds till the banner shows.

***The banners load up perfectly, minus the two lag / delay issues above. How can I resolve these?***

**Storyboard:**
[image: Storyboard]
**AppDelegate**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var adBannerView = GADBannerView()
let myBannerRequest = GADRequest()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    myBannerRequest.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.isHidden = true

    return true
}

func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
    adBannerView.isHidden = false
}
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    adBannerView.isHidden = true
}
}
```

**ViewController**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestAds()
}

internal func requestAds() {
    appDelegate.adBannerView = GADBannerView()
    appDelegate.adBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    appDelegate.adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
    appDelegate.adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    appDelegate.adBannerView.load(appDelegate.myBannerRequest)
    appDelegate.adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.height - appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height / 2)
    view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
// Same as ViewController, with addition of IBAction for the button:
@IBAction func closeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create one `GADBannerView` to use across your entire application, which is a good idea. You're not doing that though because you're creating a new `GADBannerView` in your View Controller's `requestAds` function: `appDelegate.adBannerView = GADBannerView()`. Remove it.

Also, do your request and set your Ad Unit ID in your app delegate and remove it from your `requestAds` function. In your View Controller's `viewDidLoad` you should only be positioning your `GADBannerView` and adding it to the view.

I imagine you would like the banner to fill the width of the screen too so I've changed the `frame` property. If you wanted a function for this it would end up similar to:

```
func addBannerToView() {
    appDelegate.adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
    appDelegate.adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    appDelegate.adBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                          y: view.frame.height - appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height,
                          width: view.frame.width,
                          height: appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height)
    view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)
}
```

Comment: Loads up great / Loads up on Second VC great... When clicking the close button, the ad isn't there anymore. I've experienced this before I made my initial post, that's why I had appDelegate.adBannerView = GADBannerView() in there. To try loading another one. Is there a fix for the banners not showing up when the second VC is dismissed?

Comment: Instead of viewDidLoad call the function in viewDidAppear

Comment: That works! Got an even better result (no ad flicker) using viewWillAppear. Thanks for your help here.